# Should I be avoiding @@Fetch_Status?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-cursor

After doing some reading it became apparent that multiple procedures can modify the global variable `@@Fetch_Status`.  We have a stored procedure that calls other stored procedures every hour (kind of like a table driven trigger, this way clients get control but no on has to touch but one trigger). So this parent procedure with calls these children procedures uses a cursor. Some of the child procedures could use cursors too.

I know every `Fetch Next` call is pretty much immediately followed by a `@@Fetch_Status` call but with things happening in parallel I wasn't sure if calling `@@Fetch_Status` was thread safe, especially considering the **Remarks** section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187308%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). So I thought it would be a bright idea to replace all my `While @@Fetch_Status = 0)` calls to be something like

```
WHILE ( (SELECT fetch_status
FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0)
where name = 'server_cursor')=0) BEGIN
```

This worked great on my computer but when I moved it over to a client machine I learned that I don't have select permissions on the `sys.dm_exec_cursors(0)` table. I get the error `The user does not have permission to perform this action.`.

Or alternatively, if I try `select * from sys.syscursors` I get the error `The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'syscursors', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.`

Is there another way to do this that ensures multiple simultaneous cursors do not step on each other? Or am I working too hard here?

Comment: `Returns the status of the last cursor FETCH statement issued against any cursor currently opened by the connection.` so you should only have a problem if you have an `EXEC` statement that uses a cursor between calling `FETCH` and checking the `@@Fetch_Status`.

Comment: Sure, no one procedure is written like this, but what is procA and procB both use cursors, procA calls for the next row  but before it can check the fetch status procB, in parallel, fetches it's final row thus setting the global `@@Fetch_Status` to -1. Then when procA goes to check `@@Fetch_Status`it thinks it's rows are all fetched but they're not. Or is SQL smarter than that?

Comment: Your procedures from a single connection don't run in parallel. The only thing that can run in parallel is parallel execution plans for individual queries.

Comment: Ok. What if instead ProcA and ProcB are both scheduled to be executed at 10 am. Does the server run those in parallel? or does it also do one then do the other?

Comment: If scheduled through SQL Agent they will be running under different SPIDs (connections) so won't see each other's `@@Fetch_Status`. If not please explain what you mean by "scheduled"

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. OK. So There is nothing inherently unsafe about @@Fetch_Status it seems. The MSDN documentation language and others were just making me nervous.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to check `@@FETCH_STATUS` right after your `FETCH NEXT` statement. In particular, make sure there are no intervening calls that could change the status. If necessary, you could save the value to a declared local variable. You mentioned checking the status "pretty much immediately". If you're not sure, you'd better check your code.

Otherwise, `@@FETCH_STATUS` should be reliable.